# The correct expression of the person who expanded his horizon

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I would like to express the person who expanded his horizon.
What should I express him?
I came up with two ideas: he has broad horizons, he can see the big picture.

Which is a correct expression? 
Or both of them are wrong?
Please tell me.

Comment: In the general sense both are correct. Others could be "he/she has a thirst for knowledge", "they have a desire to expand", etc.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I don't know the expression. I can understand!

Comment: You may like [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com).  Check it out!

Comment: Oh, Thank you for pointing out! I looked at this site, and I can't understand what the difference between these sites is.